# Reg: mongo db same field update

Tags: mongodb

my collection is like:
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e2664ddd692"),
       "distance" : "30F75Mg",
        "UpStreamsValue" : "300mbpsx75mbps75mbps"
    }

```
I need to add another distance column  with value 30F75M, please update me how can i use below query:

db.streams.updateMany(
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2664ddd692"),
    "distance" : "30F75Mg"
},
{
    $set:{
        "distance": "30F75M"
    }
},
{
     multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [{"elem.attributeName": "hsiaDownUpStreamsValue", "elem.attributeValue": "300mbpsx75mbps"}]
   }
);
```

Comment: You cannot have 2 fields with same name.

Comment: need to add another record with distance :30F75M  how can we acheive in same output

Comment: Could you show how your collection will look like before and after?

Comment: before 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e2664ddd692"), "distance" : "30F75Mg", "UpStreamsValue" : "300mbpsx75mbps" }

I need to add another another record 

{ "_id" : ObjectId("unique key"), "distance" : "30F75M", "UpStreamsValue" : "300mbpsx75mbps" }

Comment: @bha_25 : Do you want to add another document with same `UpStreamsValue` taken from `"_id" : ObjectId("5e2664ddd692"), "distance" : "30F75Mg"` document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to insert into the DB.

```js
db.collection.insert({"distance" : "30F75M", "UpStreamsValue" : "300mbpsx75mbps" })
```

MongoDB will it self create an unique `_id`.